# csrf TokenMismatchException in Laravel

Tags: laravel, csrf

I created a webshop using Laravel and everything has been going smoothly until recently I started getting TokenMismatchExceptions.
The users are able to log in without any problems. The issue occurs whenever a user tries to add an item to the shopping-cart. I didn't really change anything on the page, and it seems that this started to occur by it self. The only thing I did to the server was clearing the cache. Could this cause the issue to occur?

All my controllers start with:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
}
```

My sessions config is set up like this:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => 'file',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 15,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Am I using the csrf filter wrong? I can't seem to find a solution to this issue.

-EDIT-
I tried taking off my csrf filters from the controllers, and now the user gets automatically logged off when adding an item to the shopping-cart (I guess this is the problem).

Comment: [You need to send a token with your request.](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#csrf-protection)

Comment: In my views I use {{ Form::token() . Form::close() }} to close my forms. Is this not enough?

Comment: @SimonOlsen if you use `Form::open` and `Form::close` there's no need to specify the token manually with `Form::token`.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Thank you. This was something I added to see if it would fix the problem. Initially I only used Form::open and Form::close (still have the issue though).

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to look at the request that's being made when you add something to the cart, see if the CSRF token is present there.

Comment: The laravel_session request cookie is not the same as the laravel_session respond cookie. I guess this is the issue? What could cause this?